# I tried to remove my keydown event in my game in javascript but it does not have any effect

Tags: javascript, game-development

I have been building game in which the bug moves when pressed left or right. However, when game is over and I press the key the player still moves. I tried removeEventListener in my `gameover` function. It does not work at all.
This my code. Can you direct me how can I solve it.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("screen")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

//Board Dimension
boardWidth = 1000
boardHeight = 600

//Canvas dimension
canvas.width = boardWidth
canvas.height = boardHeight

// Bug Dimension
const bugWidth = 50
const bugHeight = 50

//Index of Bug and Obstacle.
obstacleIndex = 3
let bugIndex = 2

//GameOver
let isGameOver =false  

//wires
const wires =  [
    {x:canvas.width/5,y:canvas.height},
    {x:2*canvas.width/5,y:canvas.height},
    {x:3*canvas.width/5,y:canvas.height},
    {x:4*canvas.width/5,y:canvas.height}
]

const bug  = {x:wires[bugIndex].x - bugWidth * 0.5,
              y:canvas.height * 0.75 - bugHeight * 0.5}

// Obstacle Dimension
const obstacleWidth = 50;
const obstacleHeight = 50;

const obstacles_list = [
    
]

ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000"

ctx.lineWidth = 3;

//draw line function
function draw_line(){  
for(let i in wires){
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(wires[i].x,0)
    ctx.lineTo(wires[i].x,canvas.height)  
    ctx.stroke()
}
}

function createNewObstacle() {
    let randomWireIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * wires.length);
    let obstacleX = wires[randomWireIndex].x;
    let obstacleY = obstacleHeight;
    dy = 5
    return {x: obstacleX, y: obstacleY,dy:dy}
}

function isCollision(bug, obstacle) {
    // Check if the bug's rectangle intersects with the obstacle's rectangle
    return (
        bug.x < obstacle.x + obstacleWidth &&
        bug.x + bugWidth > obstacle.x &&
        bug.y < obstacle.y + obstacleHeight &&
        bug.y + bugHeight > obstacle.y
    );
}


// function to draw obstacles
function drawObstacles() {
 //Use setInterval instead of Math.random() <0.028
    if( Math.random() <0.028){
        obstacles_list.push(createNewObstacle()) 
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    for (let obstacle of obstacles_list) {
        ctx.fillRect(
            obstacle.x - obstacleWidth / 2,
            obstacle.y - obstacleHeight / 2,
            obstacleWidth,
            obstacleHeight
            )
        }
    }

function updateObstacles() {
    for (let obstacle of obstacles_list) {
        
        obstacle.y += obstacle.dy;
        console.log(isGameOver)
        if (isCollision({ x: wires[bugIndex].x, y: canvas.height * 0.75 }, obstacle)) {
            // Handle collision (e.g., end the game or reduce lives)
            isGameOver = true
            gameOver()
            change_bug_line(true)
        }

        if (obstacle.y > boardHeight) {
            obstacles_list.splice(obstacles_list.indexOf(obstacle), 1);
        }
        
    }
}
function draw_bug(shouldDraw) {
    const rectX = wires[bugIndex].x - bugWidth * 0.5;
    const rectY =  canvas.height * 0.75 - bugHeight * 0.5;
    if (shouldDraw) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(rectX, rectY, bugWidth, bugHeight);
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(rectX, rectY, bugWidth, bugHeight);
    }

}


function update_line(key){
    switch(key){
        case "ArrowLeft":
            draw_bug(false)
            bugIndex--
            if(bugIndex<0) bugIndex = 0
        break;

        case "ArrowRight":
            draw_bug(false)
            bugIndex++
            if(bugIndex>=wires.length) bugIndex = wires.length-1
        break;

    }
    draw_bug(true)
}


function change_bug_line(isGameOver){
    if(!isGameOver){window.document.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
        update_line(e.key)
    })

}}

function displayGameOverMessage() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("Game Over", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
}
function gameOver(){
        clearInterval(timerID)
        displayGameOverMessage(); 
}


function gameLoop() {
 // Only continue the game loop if the game hasn't ended
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        draw_line();
        draw_bug(true);
        updateObstacles();
        drawObstacles();
    
}

change_bug_line() //this loops contains the key event listener
const timerID= setInterval(gameLoop,1000/60) //renders my frame
```

I had tried adding removeEventListner and i though the frame of the game of would be still and keyboard would not work but still the frame was still. The key event was still capturing

Comment: Since the only way your keypresses can get processed - through a chain of calls - is via your game loop, which is based on your timer, which should be cleared at game end... I suspect your game end condition is never actually being reached. Put a console log _within_ the collision detected block, where you call gameOver(), and see if it ever gets printed in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove keydown when gameOver function called!
I don't see the part that is firing the event.
I wrote the onKeydown method here. I attached it while adding an event and used the onKeydown method to fire the event when the game ended. RemoveEventListener is used to cancel exactly that event

```js
function onKeydown(e) {
  update_line(e.key);
}

function change_bug_line(isGameOver){
    if(!isGameOver){
      window.document.addEventListener("keydown",onKeydown)
    }
}

function gameOver(){
    clearInterval(timerID);
    displayGameOverMessage();
    window.document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeydown);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was to able to solve it. It tried it but did not tried to provide a reference instead provide a reference. Super helpful